# SSL Certificate Error with Python 3 MAC OS X

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ssl-certificate, homebrew

I'm having an ssl certificate error anytime I try to download a module or data through python.

I've read that this is due to the python 3.6 install on MAC OS X which does not use the native SSL. However, I installed my python using homebrew, and the usual fix of going to `/Applications/python 3.6/Install Certificates.command` doesn't work, because that file path doesn't exist.

I also tried `pip3 install certifi` which successfully installed, but that didn't solve the issue either.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:`which python` results in `/usr/local/bin/python3`

`python3 --version` returns `python 3.6.4`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact command you use and the exact error you obtain. Add also the result of `which python3` and `python3 --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem on Mac OS X 10.11.6 using Python 3.6.4.  Here's a command and stacktrace from trying to install a Python module that is currently under development:

```
pip3 install --user dev-vcd-cli/
Processing ./dev-vcd-cli
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/: [SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

The fix seems to be to update the pbr module as follows:

```
$ pip3 install --user pbr
Collecting pbr
  Using cached pbr-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pbr
Successfully installed pbr-3.1.1
```

After this the first pip3 install command succeeded.